# Entity framework query not working using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

My entity framework query is not returning any value. I wanted to replicate this query through entity framework: SELECT name FROM guitarBrands WHERE image = image. So I ended up trying this code below.

```
public static string GetBrandByImage(string imageType)
{
    BrandsDBEntities obj = new BrandsDBEntities();

    string name = (from g in obj.guitarBrands where g.image == imageType select g.name).ToString();

    return name;
}
```

I'm really new at using entity framework and i really hope you guys can provide solutions for this.

Comment: A few things: Please provide more info, especially what exactly is returned from your query. Is it `null`? Is it an empty string? Secondly, have you tried the same query with LINQ? (`string name = (obj.Set<guitarBrands>().Where(g => g.image == imageType).Select( g => g.name).ToString();`Thirdly, you should always use `using` with contexts: `using( var obj = new BrandsDBEntities() ) { ... }`. Finally, what version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from g in obj.guitarBrands where g.image == imageType select g.name)
```

return a list like an SQL query

To get the first element

```
(from g in obj.guitarBrands where g.image == imageType select g.name).First().Tostring();
```

or equivalent

```
obj.guitarBrands.Where(g => g.image == imageType).First().name;
```

Comment: Do mention that if there are no matches and `First` is called you would get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ToString` on the query itself. Query needs to be enumerated first

```
public static string GetBrandByImage(string imageType) {
    using(var obj = new BrandsDBEntities()) {    
        var name = (from g in obj.guitarBrands 
                    where g.image == imageType 
                    select g.name).FirstOrDefault();

        return name;
    }
}
```

Using `FirstOrDefault` on the query as is would return the first `name` from any guitar brand that matches the predicate or `null` if no matches are found.